# D3.js brush.extent() wrong on IE10

Tags: html, d3.js, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to use a modified "[Focus+Context via Brushing](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367)" graph on my site.  Everything works fine on Chrome/FF/Safari.  However, when I tried it on IE10, the `brush.extent()` is shifted to the left.

What happens is that in the graph, when I click on 'April' and dragged to 'June', the resulting focus area is from slightly before 'February' to slightly before 'April'.

I believe it has something to do with the html, though I can't figure why that would cause it.  I do know that if I remove the 1st `<td>`, then the shift is much less (nearly non existent).  But I need that `<td>` for something else.

Here's my HTML:

```
 <div style="zoom:1; width:960px; display: block;">
     <table style="margin: 10px 0; max-width: 100%; background-color: transparent; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display:
 table; zoom: 1;">
         <tbody style="display: table-row-group; vertical-align: middle; border-color: inherit; border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 2px; border-color: gray; zoom: 1;">
             <tr style="width: 960px; height: 62px; display: table-row; vertical-align: inherit; border-color: inherit;">&nbsp;</tr>
             <tr style="width: 960px; height: 62px; display: table-row; vertical-align: inherit; border-color: inherit;">
                 <td style="width: 232px; vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;</td>
                 <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; display: table-cell;">
                     <div style="display: block; width: 665px; text-align: center;">
                         <div class='graph_container_div' is-loaded='false'>
                             <div id='line_chart' class='compartment_half' style='height:375px'></div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table> 
</div>
```

my full example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scripterX/3Ufqk/2/

My data array has 3 values because I will ultimately convert this graph to show 3 line graphs with focus instead of the area graph that it is now.

Comment: Have you tried it with just the SVG, not embedded in a table?  Can you also clarify what you mean by "the `brush.extent()` is shifted to the left".  Does the rectangle not match the cursor on the context graph, or does the focus graph not match the context rectangle?  It could just be that the cursor's center point (from the operating system's perspective) doesn't match the visual center of the icon...

Comment: What I meant by "the brush.extent() is shifted to the left" is that when I click on the context and drag to highlight an area the highlighted area (and the resulting highlighted area) is shifted to the left of the actual mouse click.

Comment: Looks like it's a known issue related to IE giving incorrect mouse coordinates when the user has zoomed the browser window:  https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/668  You could try this patch created by another user: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/766

Comment: Thanks, AmeliaBR!!!  I used the JS suggested and it worked for me!  Please write that as an answer so I can mark it as the correct fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by browsers giving an incorrect conversion between the SVG coordinate system and the screen when the user has changed the zoom setting in the browser.  It is described in this d3 github issue:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/668

It apparently was a problem in older Chrome versions that has since been fixed.  But with IE we can't count on users having the latest browser versions...

User vogievetsky on github [has proposed a workaround](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/766) which tests for the bug and makes corrections if necessary.  Although it hasn't been integrated into the main d3, it is available as a patch -- just add his script to your page sometime after loading d3 and before using any mouse functions:

https://github.com/vogievetsky/KoalasToTheMax/blob/master/d3.mouse.patch.js